# jar file not working properly Failed to load driver and images

Tags: java, odbc, executable-jar

I've created an application for inventory management system in net beans. I've used Ms Access to store database.It works fine in netbeans.but after i've created jar file of it,it displays error as "Failed to load Driver". I've also included flash screen in my program(which displays an image for 10 seconds).but on runnig the jar file,this image is not shown.only a blank box (which is same as image size) is displayed and then the error "Failed to load driver" is displayed in CMD. Can any one please suggest solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to include the library jars when you deployed it?  Where are the images stored in relationship to the source code?  How are you loading the images?

Comment: Images are stored in the folder "IMAGES" and it is in the project's directory. and i dont know how to include libraries in jar file.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using to access MSAccess?  You need to included the "images" directory along with your application

Comment: I'm using jdbc:odbc driver. nd how to include images directory? because all the libraries are stored in netbeans default directory.

Comment: Once you do a clean and build in Netbeans, it creates a `dist` directory, which contains you application jar (and any dependencies).  Copy the "images" directory into this directory.  You should then be able distributed it all together.  Have you setup the odbc entry on the system you're trying to run it?  I might also add that I believe that the odbc/jdbc bridge has been deprecated and has issues with been run at different levels (64bit JVM, 32bit odbc)

Comment: i have done with setup for odbc entry on my system. still it is showing error that failed to load driver.

Comment: What is the OS bit level?  32 or 64 bit?  What about Java, 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: OS bit level:32 bit nd java also 32 bit